# Best way to make a selfmade Long-Range WiFi Link

Tags: antenna, diy, wifi

What needs to be considered?

Which type of antenna(only self-made or reused parts, for example satellite dish) is the best for a long range, high throughput WiFi? How to calculate Antenna size and shape? Which characteristics of the WiFi Module play a role for this application?

Long-Range WiFi for LOS.

You can share also any results of your own application.

Comment: http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/352/what-is-a-link-budget-and-how-do-i-make-one

Comment: http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/6346/looking-to-test-line-of-sight-radio-at-5ghz-at-range-25km-or-less-any-help

Answer (score 1):

A 2.4Ghz parabolic dishes reflect into/from a 12.5cm yagi pointed at the centre. I suppose you could be flexible with the dish diameter, but the yagi must be correctly made ( with reflector and director ), and you can't expect good results long-range with a yagi shorter than one full wavelength. If you are in an area with much traffic on 2.4GHz, use 5GHz instead. Ubiquiti networks used to sell pretty good cards for long-range links, but I suppose you can get by with some Alfa USB cards on the endpoints. Remember to use coax for antenna cables. If you are truly serious about DIY:
http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=WkXsS-kTtPo
http://www.instructables.com/id/Wifi-Signal-Strainer-WokFi/
http://lifehacker.com/5053796/boost-your-wi-fi-signal-with-cooking-strainer
Try to keep endpoints using identical operating systems. Tomato *WRT, whichever is most effective.

Comment: Should mention that I get 80-90mbit/s on 5G in a place where 2.4G only (not any hybrid mode) yields 15-25mbit/s.